# Storing values corresponding to an unique key in perl

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. I want to store the values corresponding to the keys in the following fashion. Please see below for a sample input data. Could someone help me to do this in perl.

output:

```
key  value
1  (11, 20)
2  (17, 15)
3  (10, 11)
```

Input data:

```
key value
2    17
3    10
1    11 
1   20
2    15
3    11
```

Answer (score 4):

You can store the data in a hash-of-arrays structure ([perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

my %data;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ($k, $v) = split;
    push @{ $data{$k} } , $v;
}

print Dumper(\%data);

=for output

$VAR1 = {
          '1' => [
                   '11',
                   '20'
                 ],
          '2' => [
                   '17',
                   '15'
                 ],
          '3' => [
                   '10',
                   '11'
                 ]
        };

=cut


__DATA__
2    17
3    10
1    11 
1    20
2    15
3    11
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each of the lines in the input data is in 
a string, use a hash which has unique keys by definition.

If the key exists in the hash push the value onto the arrayref. 
If it doesn't exist assign an array reference to the key with the 
value. Next time that key appears you'll push the value onto the arrayref.

```
my $hash = {};

foreach my $line ( @lines ) {
     my ($key, $val) = split(/\s/, $line);

     if( $hash->{$key} ) {
         push( @{ $hash->{ $key } }, $val );
     }
     else {
         $hash->{$key} = [ $val ];
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The data is in a text file. Do I need to put <> inplace of @lines. Please let me know.

Comment: Looks like you use the part that toolic used above. Replace the foreach line with the while( <DATA> ) { line.

Comment: You don't have to create an array with that else block. Autovivification handles it.

Answer (score -1):

Using oneliner:

```
$ echo "key value
2    17
3    10
1    11 
1   20
2    15
3    11" | perl -anE'next if 1..1;push@{$h{$F[0]}},$F[1]}{say"key  value";$"=", ";say"$_  (@{$h{$_}})"for sort{$a<=>$b}keys%h'
key  value
1  (11, 20)
2  (17, 15)
3  (10, 11)
```